# Android OpenGL: Pixel-Perfect collision without bitmap data

Tags: android, opengl-es, collision-detection

Due to some memory problems I had to *textureBitmap.recycle()* all texture bitmaps after I created an OpenGL texture. Works great and there is enough memory left.

My problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to implement collision detection. 
I dont want just boundingbox tests - thats pretty easy - I want pixel perfect collision detection. I don't use any engine, so I cant use existing libraries. 
Before working without an engine I used an extension for the AndEngine which worked pixel perfect!

Can you give me a hint, how to implement the collision detection?

Comment: Are you working in 2D or 3D? There's a pretty good article at http://sacredsoftware.net/tutorials/Collisions/CollisionsPart1.html that might get you started...

Comment: Are you doing just 2D game with OpenGL? Here "pixel collisions" can make sense. In 3D it's sensless.
Also, what kind of collision you mean? Point against polygone? Two polygones against each other?

Comment: I already have a solution. I am creating bitmasks of both texture bitmaps and store these masks. The bitmap will be recyled but the masks can still be used. Works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pixel perfect collision library](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect) I made for andengine includes a [PixelPerfectBitmask](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect/blob/master/src/com/qwerjk/andengine/collision/PixelPerfectBitMask.java) that will work on its own.

```
PixelPerfectBitmask mask1 = new PixelPerfectBitmask(bmp1, 100, 100);
PixelPerfectBitmask mask2 = new PixelPerfectBitmask(bmp2, 100, 100);
Log.v("pp collision", String.valueOf(mask1.collidesWith(mask2, 20, 10)));
```

If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: How can I detect collision when I rotate one sprite 90 degree? How can I rotate the bitmask too?

Comment: The bitmasks only work in one direction. You'll need to rotate the bitmap and regenerate the bitmask. Alternately, you could extend the bitmasks with a rotate() method, but it would require some thought. If you go that route and don't mind sharing, be sure to let me know!

Comment: At the time of rotation the bitmap dosent exsists anymore. I have to rotate the bitmasks which will be quiet hard to implement :)

Comment: You could of course generate multiple bitmasks while you still have the data. Rotating the bitmasks shouldn't be too difficult though (assuming you only need 90 degree increments), you'll just need to be careful about your axis of rotation.

Comment: Yeah but I need every angle :)